# how can i match html tags with no id with deface

Tags: spree

Trying to add a column to a table in the configuration menu, the table has a empty `<th> </th>` just for looks, but when i add the column, it adds it after this so looks ugly, adding it with this

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/admin/user_groups/index",
    :name         => "minimum_order_column",
    :insert_after => "code[erb-loud]:contains('description')",
    :partial      => "spree/admin/user_groups/minimum_order_column")
```

first weird thing is that it adds it after that empty th, but seems like a easy fix if I could just remove it

`admin/user_groups` is from [spree_user_groups](https://github.com/levymetal/spree_user_groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deface uses CSS selectors in general to do it's dirty work.

You should be able to do `th[3]` or `th:last` to find that `<th>`

---

http://deface.heroku.com/ is a great tool to help in testing selectors.